# Swift Group Sequential Objects in Array

Tags: arrays, swift, grouping, swift5

I have the following array of objects:

```
[Car, Train, Train, Motorbike, Train, Car, Car]
```

I would like to group any object of the same type that follow one another resulting into the following:

```
[Car, [Train, Train], Motorbike, Train, [Car, Car]]
```

or even better:

```
[Car, GroupOfVehicles(type: .train, vehicles:[Train, Train]), Motorbike, Train, GroupOfVehicles(type: .car, vehicles:[Car, Car])
```

I have found some SO posts about grouping by property but I need to keep the sequential nature of the array intact.

For those interested in my objective: I would like to present objects in a table one below the other, but if there is a group of similar sequential objects, they should show all on the same 'row' and thus the user will scroll through them horizontally.

Comment: Are you using any protocol or superclass for your vehicle types?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution based on an array of `Any` but if the types all conform to a common protocol or has a common superclass then this hopefully can be solved in a more effective way.

```
var grouped: [[Any]] = []
var previous: String = ""
motors.forEach {
    let vehicleType = "\(type(of: $0))"
    if vehicleType != previous {
        grouped.append([$0])
        previous = vehicleType
    } else {
        grouped[grouped.count - 1].append($0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `chunked(by:)` function from open source swift package [Swift Alogrithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms)

```swift
import Algorithms

protocol X {} // Assuming that you have protocol or superclass 
struct A: X {}; struct B: X {}; struct C: X {}

let arr: [X] = [A(), A(), B(), C(), C(), C(), B(), A()]

let chunks = arr.chunked { type(of: $0) == type(of: $1) }

// You should have something like this [ArraySlice([A(), A()]), ArraySlice([B()]), ArraySlice([C(), C(), C()]), ArraySlice([B()]), ArraySlice([A()])]
```

And you can transform this collection further as you need.